# How to configure MySQL on same machine with different port?

Tags: mysql, port, my.cnf

How to configure two different port for MySQL on same machine? I know that default port is 3306. But I also want to configure 3307 and 3308. Is it possible?

**One bonus question with current one ;)**

Can we assign Different Ports to Different Databases and also can assign/create Credentials respectively?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `--port=port_num` option. Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html) for more information on how to configure multiple mysql instances.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. Can you provide sample config settings? Just for better understanding?

Comment: Not really - I don't have such at my disposal right now. I will have to look through the document but I encourage you to do so on your own,

Comment: I will look and if have any query will ask.

Answer (score 7):

You can launch several instance of mysql :

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf1
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf2
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/path/to/my.cnf3
```

and change the **port** parameter in the [mysqld] section of each my.cnf.

If you want to have only one mysqld process/database you can use port redirection (with linux) :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3307 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3308 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

Comment: Can I assign two different ports (3307 and 3308) to two different databases (dba and dbb)?

Comment: In order to do that, you need to run 2 different mysqld instances, create `dba` in the first one and `dbb` in the second one.

Answer (score 5):

You can copy `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, change the port in it and change the pathes to data dirs as well, because i'm pretty sure You can't have more than 1 instance of mysql serving from the same directories.

Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html.

ex :

```
cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my-3307.cnf
//edit my-3307.cnf, for example
port = 3307
basedir = /var/lib/mysql-3307
datadir = /var/lib/mysql-3307
//end-edit
mysql_upgrade --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my-3307.cnf #checks the syntax and creates the dirs you need.
#start mysqld
mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my-3307.cnf
```

Comment: Nicely provided info :) I appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

[mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html) is by far the best way to handle different instances of mysql.

Some more useful tips:

- `mysqld_multi --example`
- check if apparmor isn't keeping mysql from accessing `/var/lib/mysql2` if you get weird permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CentOS.
Not is too simple,

1. Edit file **/etc/my.cnf**, Search and change or add line: port=***port_number***.
2. semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp ***port_number***
3. Restart MySQL Server. **service mysqld restart**